# Como puedo hacerle para validar un email en javascript?

Tags: javascript

Tengo este código que funciona correctamente para los email "Ordinarios" 
ejemplo:
nombre de usuario + @ + servidor + dominio
correodeprueba@hotmail.com

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.([a-zA-Z]{2,4})+$/
```

Pero qué tengo que anexarle para poder agregar lo siguiente

nombre de usuario + @ + servidor + dominio + pais
Ejemplo:
correodeprueba@hotmail.com.MX

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Usar regex para validar emails es generalmente una mala idea. Pero, aparte de eso, ¿qué es lo que has probado? Porque tal y como está tu expresión regular ¡[la cadena que quieres valida sin hacer ningún cambio](https://regex101.com/r/PSaJmJ/1/)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Este es el pattern:

```
/^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/
```

```js
$(function(){
  $(document).on('keyup','#foo',function(){
    var val = $(this).val().trim(),
        reg = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    if( reg.test(val) == false ){
      console.log('NO es un mail');
    }
    
    else{
      console.log('SI es un mail');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="foo">
```

Apóyate con esta herramienta [Regexper](https://regexper.com/) está brutal.

Comment: Me imagino que [ésta es la fuente del regex que compartes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46181/3695983). En los comentarios podrás ver que se comenta que contiene fallos y que considera emails válidos cadenas que son no válidas como `"a..b"@gmail.com` o `me's@mess.co.uk.in`.

Comment: Supongo, hace mucho tiempo tuve el mismo problema y ahora es el regex que uso en mis códigos, no sabría decirte si es la misma fuente.

Comment: Muchas gracias!